# When variable changes update view in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there a way to pass information to the view from the model when information changes such as a new post in a messaging app.

My controller:

```
function commentsController($scope, $http){

    $http.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8';

    $http.get("index.php?action=getComments")
         .success(function(data){ $scope.comments = data;  });

    $scope.addComment = function(comment){
        if("undefined" != comment.msg){
            $http({
                method : "POST",
                url : "index.php", 
                data : "action=add&msg="+comment.msg
              }).success(function(data){
                  $scope.comments.unshift(data); 
              });
            $scope.comment = "";
        }
    }

    $scope.deleteComment = function(index){
        $http({
              method : "GET",
              url : "index.php?action=delete&id="+$scope.comments[index].id,
        }).success(function(data){
            $scope.comments.splice(index,1);
        });
    }
 }
```

My index.php:

```
<div>
    <textarea name="submitComment" ng-model="comment.msg" placeholder="What are you thinking?"></textarea>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="button" ng-click="addComment(comment)">POST</a>
    </div>

      <!-- Comments -->
    <div ng-repeat="comment in comments">
       <div class="updates">
          <a href="javascript:void(0);" ng-click="deleteComment($index);" style='float:right'>Delete</a>
          {{comment.msg}}
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Anything helps, Gab

Comment: what about updating every xx secondes `$scope.comments` with the [`$timeout`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) service?

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap the chunk of code you want to update in $apply() function.